# Convert rownames of a matrix from character to POSIX

Tags: r, date, posixct, posixlt

I don't know how to convert the rows of a matrix in R from character to POSIXt or another similar class. These are my character rows:

```
  [1] "2015.07.06 13.41.00.033" "2015.07.06 13.40.00.033" "2015.07.06 13.39.00.033"
  [4] "2015.07.06 13.38.00.033" "2015.07.06 13.37.00.007" "2015.07.06 13.36.00.007"
  [7] "2015.07.06 13.35.00.007" "2015.07.06 13.34.00.007" "2015.07.06 13.33.00.007"
 [10] "2015.07.06 13.32.00.007" "2015.07.06 13.31.00.007" "2015.07.06 13.30.00.007"
 [13] "2015.07.06 13.29.00.007" "2015.07.06 13.28.00.007" "2015.07.06 13.27.00.007"
 [16] "2015.07.06 13.26.00.007" "2015.07.06 13.25.00.007" "2015.07.06 13.24.00.007"
 [19] "2015.07.06 13.23.00.007"
```

Comment: What is the general format of the time? Is it "Year.Month.Day Hours.Minutes.Seconds.Milliseconds"?

Answer (score 1):

A matrix can only contain one type of data, unlike a list or data.frame.  Additionally, a matrix (usually) only contains atomic types*, which means your `POSIXct` object would be converted to numeric.

```
> matrix(Sys.time())
           [,1]
[1,] 1436191385
```

So the answer to your question is, "you can't do that with a matrix." Use a data.frame instead, or provide more detail in your question about what problem you're actually trying to solve by doing this.

*A matrix can contain list elements, which are not atomic objects, but that is a very unusual case and likely not what the user intended.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
options(digits.secs=6)
times <- strptime(times,"%Y.%m.%d %H.%M.%OS", tz= " ")
#> times
# [1] "2015-07-06 13:41:00.033" "2015-07-06 13:40:00.033" "2015-07-06 13:39:00.033" "2015-07-06 13:38:00.033" "2015-07-06 13:37:00.007"
# [6] "2015-07-06 13:36:00.007" "2015-07-06 13:35:00.007" "2015-07-06 13:34:00.007" "2015-07-06 13:33:00.007" "2015-07-06 13:32:00.007"
#[11] "2015-07-06 13:31:00.007" "2015-07-06 13:30:00.007" "2015-07-06 13:29:00.007" "2015-07-06 13:28:00.007" "2015-07-06 13:27:00.007"
#[16] "2015-07-06 13:26:00.007" "2015-07-06 13:25:00.007" "2015-07-06 13:24:00.007" "2015-07-06 13:23:00.007"
#> class(times)
#[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

## data

```
times <-c("2015.07.06 13.41.00.033", "2015.07.06 13.40.00.033", "2015.07.06 13.39.00.033",
"2015.07.06 13.38.00.033", "2015.07.06 13.37.00.007", "2015.07.06 13.36.00.007",
"2015.07.06 13.35.00.007", "2015.07.06 13.34.00.007", "2015.07.06 13.33.00.007",
"2015.07.06 13.32.00.007", "2015.07.06 13.31.00.007" ,"2015.07.06 13.30.00.007",
"2015.07.06 13.29.00.007", "2015.07.06 13.28.00.007", "2015.07.06 13.27.00.007",
"2015.07.06 13.26.00.007", "2015.07.06 13.25.00.007", "2015.07.06 13.24.00.007",
"2015.07.06 13.23.00.007")
```

If you want to use these POSIXt entries for a time series of your data, a convenient way could consist in converting the dataframe into an `xts` object.

This could be achieved, e.g., with

```
library(xts)
my_xts <- xts(times, data)
```

where `data` are the observations, stored as numerical values, that correspond to the above sequence of points in time.

Hope this helps.